# Save webview as pdf in form of multiple pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

How to save a webview that has an image(s),

I have tried by taking snapshots of webview, but it is cropping the image or text in that frame. So is there anything to render dynamically(where the height of the pdf should be dynamic). I have gone through all existing answers, but everything is giving the same result. can some one assist the same with the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very nice open source project available at below link:

https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf

It has below two methods which you can explore to create the PDF from webView:

```
+ (id)createPDFWithURL:(NSURL*)URL pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath delegate:(id <NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate>)delegate pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins;
+ (id)createPDFWithHTML:(NSString*)HTML pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath delegate:(id <NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate>)delegate pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins;
```

Comment: the link you have given is really useful.